# Unit test for Api controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I try to write a unit test for a Api Controller. It is a C# mvc application. And the unit test also works with Moq.

This is the controller:

```
public sealed class CaseController : ApiControllerBase
{    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public ICaseDto<object> Get(int id)
    {
        return _caseProcess.GetCase(id);
    }
}
```

And this is the interface:

```
public interface ICaseProcess
{
    ICaseDto<object> GetCase(int id);
}
```

And this is the method:

```
internal sealed class CaseProcess : ProcessBase, ICaseProcess
{
    public ICaseDto<object> GetCase(int id)
    {
        var caseEntity = GetCaseById(id);

        CaseProcessHelper helper = GetHelper(caseEntity);
        object details = helper.GetReferenceDetails();

        ICaseDto<object> resultDto = CaseDto.Create(details);
        Mapper.Map(caseEntity, resultDto);
        return resultDto;
    }
}
```

And I try to write the Unit test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CaseConroller_ReturnDetailData_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var dto = new Case();
    var mockService = new Mock<ICaseProcess>();
    var Casecontroller = new CaseController(ICaseDto<Case>);
    var expected = new CaseEditDto();
    //var dataSource = new

    CaseProcess.Setup(a => a.Should(dto))

    //Act

    // var result = "hallo";

    //Assert
    result.Should().BeEquivalentTo();
}
```

So how exactly you have to write the Unit test?

I have a Detail view and then the Api has to return the data of the detail view.

The id is an int, like this: `api/support/cases/100000002`.

The constructor looks like this:

```
 public CaseController(ICaseProcess caseProcess)
        {
            _caseProcess = caseProcess;
        }
```

I have it now like this:

```
 //Arrange
            var dto = new Case();
            var mockService = new Mock<ICaseProcess>();
            var casecontroller = new CaseController(CaseProcess.Object);
            var expected = new CaseEditDto();

            //Act

             var result = casecontroller.Get(100000001);

            //Assert
            result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

But the output is like this:

```
{
    "details": {
        "name": "Val van Urquhart",
        "dateOfBirth": "11 september 1933"
    },
    "dateSubmittedFormatted": "1 januari 2018",
    "dateClosedFormatted": null,
    "sample": false,
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "account": "todo@local.nl",
            "date": "08-11-2018 17:13",
            "text": "ABC"
        }
    ],
    "id": 100000001,
    "status": 103,
    "substatus": null,
    "verdict": null,
    "owner": 101,
    "dateSubmitted": "01-01-2018",
    "dateClosed": null,
    "type": 100,
    "reference": "123459850"
}
```

I try it like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void CaseController_GetCase_Test()
        {
            var CaseObject = new CaseDto<object>()
            {
                Id = 100000001,
                Verdict = null,                
                DateSubmitted = "01-01-2018",
                DateClosed = null,
                Reference = "123459850"

            };        




            var CaseTest = new CaseEditDto<object>();
            // Case entity =   UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Case>()

        }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" test to test something. You have to describe exactly **what** you want to test. This includes every input and the expected output of your member. In other words: what should your method do when it is provided with the following set of args... what should it do when using this set of args, and so on. There may be hundreds of tests to test even a single method.

Comment: Anyway you din´t show us the constructor of your controler. I assume it expects an instance of `ICaseProcess`. In this case `new CaseController(ICaseDto<Case>);` wouldn´t even compile.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the shown snippets the assumption is that the controller looks something like

```
public sealed class CaseController : ApiControllerBase {
    private readonly ICaseProcess caseProcess;

    public CaseController(ICaseProcess caseProcess) {
        this.caseProcess = caseProcess;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public ICaseDto<object> Get(int id) {
        return caseProcess.GetCase(id);
    }
}
```

A very simple test would be to mock the dependency, inject it into the subject under test, exercise the test and then assert the expected behavior

```
[TestMethod]
public void CaseConroller_ReturnDetailData_Test() {
    //Arrange
    //mock the dependency
    var id = 100000001;
    var expected = Mock.Of<ICaseDto<object>>();
    var mockService = new Mock<ICaseProcess>();
    mockService.Setup(_ => _.GetCase(id)).Returns(expected);
    //inject it into the subject under test
    var subject = new CaseController(mockService.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = subject.Get(id); //exercise the test

    //Assert
    //assert the expected behavior
    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you ok

Comment: That is the data of the Edit case

Comment: What *Edit* case? Did you try my suggested answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that works. But now it is with the properties of the object